# How to configure MassTransit with Mediator to publish messages?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, masstransit

I'm new with **MassTransit** and **Mediator**, I have a series of events to execute in consecutive order, I'm using **MassTransit** in-process and in-memory, for my use case no transport is required.

I want to send and publish messages to consumers, sagas, activities through Mediator, I have the code below, but I want to improve it by registering MassTransit in `startup.cs`:

```cs
//asp net core 3.1 Controller

 [ApiController]
 public class MyController : ControllerBase
 {    
    private readonly IProductService _productService ;
    private readonly IMediator mediator;
    public MyController(IProductService productService)
    {
       _productService = productService;
      var repository = new InMemorySagaRepository<ApiSaga>();
      mediator = Bus.Factory.CreateMediator(cfg =>
      {
          cfg.Saga<ProductSaga>(repository);
      });
    }
   
     [HttpPost]
     public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] ProductContract productContract)
     {            
         try
         {
             var result = await _productService.DoSomeThingAsync(productContract);
             await mediator.Publish<ProductSubmittedEvent>(new { CorrelationId = Guid.NewGuid(), result.Label });
         return Ok();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             return BadRequest(ex.Message);
         }
      }
 }

//My saga
public class ProductSaga :
        ISaga,
        InitiatedBy<ProductSubmittedEvent>
    {
        public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
        public string State { get; private set; } = "Not Started";

        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ProductSubmittedEvent> context)
        {
            var label= context.Message.Label;
            State = "AwaitingForNextStep";
            //...
           //send next command
        }
    }
```

Like this it works but it's not proper, I want to configure masstransit with Mediator in my `startup.cs` to have one proper instance, to do that I started by deleting the `IMediator`, using an `IPublishEndpoint` to publish messages to `Saga` and configuring my `startup.cs`, but it doesn't work as expected:

```cs
//startup.cs

 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
      services.AddMediator(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddSaga<ProductSaga>().InMemoryRepository();
            });
 }

//in controller using:
private readonly IPublishEndpoint _publishEndpoint;

//then
await _publishEndpoint.Publish<ProductSubmittedEvent>(
    new { CorrelationId = Guid.NewGuid(), result.Label });
```

I got a `System.InvalidOperationException`:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'MassTransit.IPublishEndpoint' while attempting to activate 'GaaS.API.Controllers.ManageApiController'.

I tried to update my `startup.cs`:

```cs
var repository = new InMemorySagaRepository<ApiSaga>();
            services.AddMassTransit(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddBus(provider =>
                {
                    return Bus.Factory.CreateMediator(x =>
                    {
                        x.Saga<ProductSaga>(repository);
                    });
                });
            });
```

I got:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'MassTransit.Mediator.IMediator' to 'MassTransit.IBusControl'.

If you have any recommendation ideas thanks for sharing and challenging me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way to configure MassTransit Mediator in your project is through the `Startup.cs` file, which you seem to have tried.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMediator(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddSaga<ProductSaga>().InMemoryRepository();
    });
}
```

Using mediator, you need to depend upon the `IMediator` interface. You cannot use `IPublishEndpoint` or `ISendEndpointProvider`, as those are bus interfaces. Since you can have both mediator and a bus instance in the container at the same time, this would lead to confusion when resolving services from the container.

```
[ApiController]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{    
    private readonly IProductService _productService ;
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public MyController(IProductService productService, IMediator mediator)
    {
        _productService = productService;
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] ProductContract productContract)
    {            
        try
        {
            var result = await _productService.DoSomeThingAsync(productContract);
            
            await _mediator.Publish<ProductSubmittedEvent>(new { CorrelationId = NewId.NextGuid(), result.Label });

            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

If you are only using mediator, and want to use `IPublishEndpoint`, you could add that to the container yourself and delegate it.

```
services.AddSingleton<IPublishEndpoint>(provider => provider.GetService<IMediator>());
```

Comment: Thanks for your clarification and getting back to me

Comment: how can I use `services.AddMassTransitHostedService()` in this use case when using `services.AddMediator(...)`?

Comment: There is no need, mediator is neither started nor stopped, it's available immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I got to this from the (excellent) [youtube video - MassTransit starting with Mediator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxHNAn69x6w), in that sample there is a line of code

```cs
AddMediator()
```

which I couldn't locate. I believe the following setup provides everything needed to get code working based on that video...

```cs
            services.AddMassTransit(config =>
            {
                config.AddRequestClient<ISubmitOrder>();
                config.AddConsumersFromNamespaceContaining<SubmitOrderConsumer>();

                config.UsingInMemory(ConfigureBus);
            });
```

and `ConfigureBus` is then:

```cs
        private void ConfigureBus(IBusRegistrationContext context, IInMemoryBusFactoryConfigurator configurator)
        {
            configurator.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
        }
```

I couldn't readily find this elsewhere, hence posting here.